# Why use flatMap or filter when all could be done in the subscriber?

Tags: android, rx-java

Why should I use `flatMap`, `filter`, and etc. if I could do the same (filter data) thing in subscribe part?

```
  api
            .getTweetRx()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) //отдаем новый тред для работы в background
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //говорим, что обсервить хотим в main thread
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<Tweet>, Observable<Tweet>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Tweet> call(List<Tweet> tweets) {
                    return Observable.from(tweets);
                }
            })

        .filter(new Func1<Tweet, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Tweet tweet) {
                if (tweet.getImage()!="")
                return true;
                else return false;
            }
        })

            .subscribe(new Action1<Tweet>() {
                           @Override
                           public void call(Tweet tweet) {
                               tweets.add(tweet);
                           }
                       },
                    new Action1<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                            Log.d("!!!ERROR", "" + throwable);
                        }
                    },
                    new Action0() { // onComplite
                        @Override
                        public void call() { // // on main thread; all photo's loaded, time to show the list or something.
                            final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tweet_list);
                            myList.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(tweets, MainActivity.this));
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: If you use filter, your code will be clean and you won't have to write any if instructions or something like that in subscribe part. You will just get data, which you want to get.

Comment: and that is all? just to make code cleaner? and where does the "filter" run? on main thread?

Comment: It also implements `Operator` from RxJava which gives you error handling. It's helpful in the case when something will go wrong with filtering. In addition, it has unit tests in RxJava project what guarantees stability of that method. If you write your own filtering functionality you will actually "re-invent the wheel" and you will have to care about its stability and testability by yourself.

Comment: Well, I think a large part of using RxJava in the first place is to make the code cleaner and easier to understand. It does not give you any computational power that you couldn't have otherwise written in a more ad hoc way. If you put everything in the `Subscriber`, you could just as well have used any other async callback instead of Rx. Also, while filtering is very easy to do ad hoc, I think that `flatMap` or `combineLatest` are a bit more error prone. And `filter` does not run on any particular thread, I think - it just stays on the same thread the upstream `Obervable` was on.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about separation of concerns (and leveraging others' work to cut the time needed to finish your work).

Compare the following code and decide yourself which approach suits your needs (the code's in Scala, though, to further leverage others' work - to cut the boilerplate).

`Sample.ints` is an `Observable[Int]`.

```
Sample.ints.subscribe(new Subscriber[Int] {
  override def onStart(): Unit = println("+++ onStart")
  override def onNext(n: Int): Unit = println(s"+++ onNext: [$n]")
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(s"+++ onError: [$e]")
  override def onCompleted(): Unit = println(s"+++ onCompleted")
})
```

As you may have noticed the subscriber doesn't do much, just prints what comes in.

```
+++ onStart
+++ onNext: [0]
+++ onNext: [1]
+++ onNext: [2]
+++ onNext: [3]
+++ onNext: [4]
+++ onNext: [5]
+++ onNext: [6]
+++ onNext: [7]
+++ onNext: [8]
+++ onNext: [9]
+++ onNext: [10]
+++ onCompleted
```

Let's say I want to filter out odds. I don't have to change the subscriber's code, say it doesn't belong to me, e.g. I've got no source code to modify and use.

Using `filter` is so simple.

```
Sample.ints.filter(_ % 2 == 0).subscribe(new Subscriber[Int] {
  override def onStart(): Unit = println("+++ onStart")
  override def onNext(n: Int): Unit = println(s"+++ onNext: [$n]")
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println(s"+++ onError: [$e]")
  override def onCompleted(): Unit = println(s"+++ onCompleted")
})
```

Look ma, no odds now - you only had to add the integration part - the glue between the observable and the subscriber.

```
+++ onStart
+++ onNext: [0]
+++ onNext: [2]
+++ onNext: [4]
+++ onNext: [6]
+++ onNext: [8]
+++ onNext: [10]
+++ onCompleted
```

I could change the subscriber, but only if you've got the source code - think what's possible when you don't.

And so on...